# WPML: Don't use language parameters in the URL and use/set languages globally (and not post-related)

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

My website uses English as default language and German/DE as second language.

I want to achieve the following:

1. No language paramter should ever be in the URL (no /de or ?lang=de).
2. The available language metadata tags in the  are post-related/post-dependent, why is that? I want it to be globally,
   so I also want to show the DE tag when the current post is not
   available in German.
3. Assuming the browser's language is DE, use DE as the website's language globally, so show all contents (including post and
   non-post contents) which are available in German in German, contents which have no German translation are shown in the English
   default language.
4. The language can be globally changed in the footer, a cookie/option is then set which has a higher priority than the browser language
   detection.

Example URLs:

- Front page

  - EN & DE: website.com
- Blog page:

  - EN & DE: website.com/blog
- About page:

  - EN: website.com/about
  - DE: website.com/ueber
- Specific project (CPT)

  - EN: website.com/projects/animals
  - DE: website.com/projekte/tiere

How can this be achieved with WPML?

Are there any SEO disadvantages? Do I have to consider anything, e.g. when the URL is the same for multiple languages/contents?

I like short URLs and want to avoid having the language in there. And if the current post is not available in German, it must still be possible to show the website in German, because all the other non-post contents of the website are available in German.

Thank you!